# How to come out of Area Controller in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

My url routing is working properly inside "Areas" folder, that means i can go to any controller or view from one to another, how can i come out of this Area controller to Parent Controller?

For Ex:  in my controller if i give this line it is coming out of Area controller and working properly

```
//Homecontroller.cs inside Controllers folder
return RedirectToAction("../../Home");
```

What is the proper way of coding to come out and connect to parent controller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the area explicitly. Area is a routing parameter, just like controller and action. If you don't specify it explicitly when generating a URL (i.e. when calling RedirectToAction) the current value is assumed. Which is the area of the current controller.

For example:

```
return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home", new {Area = "Test"} );
```

To return to a top-level controller clear the area like so:

```
return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home", new {Area = ""} );
```

Comment: i do not want to go any Area, just come out from Area and go to parent project Controller

Comment: Then set `Area=""` that should return you to the top level.

Comment: No, even this is not working, we should not consider Area anywhere

Comment: No Problem it is working now with your same answer, i cleaned little bit in my routing, it is working perfect